# :active selector for custom li tag bullets

Tags: html, css

I have the following problem:

I have a `ul` with blue list item text and a blue custom bullet. Now if the user clicks a `li` the text should be black and the custom bullet as well.

The text is easy to change, but i don't know how i could do it, that the custom bullet also stays black.

When the user hovers trough the menu the custom bullets and the text turns black. This is already working. But if the user is on a page, as soon he leaves the hover area the bullets turn blue again. This shoud not be the case.

Here is what i have already:

```
<ul class="listMenuItem--s">
                    <li class="listMenuChild">
                        <a href="#" class="listMenuChild--title active">Dienstleistungen</a>
                        <ul class="sub-nav">
                            <li><a href="service/treuhandf.html" class="listMenuChild--subtitle">Treuhand &amp; Finanzen </a></li>
                            <li><a href="service/wirtschaft.html" class="listMenuChild--subtitle">Wirtschaftsprüfung</a></li>
                            <li><a href="service/unternehmen.html" class="listMenuChild--subtitle">Unternehmensberatung / Nachfolge</a></li>
                            <li><a href="service/pension.html" class="listMenuChild--subtitle">Pensionierungs-, Vorsorge- und Steuerplanung</a></li>
                            <li><a href="service/informatik.html" class="listMenuChild--subtitle">Informatik</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="listMenuChild">
                        <a href="about.html" class="listMenuChild--title">Über uns</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="listMenuChild">
                        <a href="publications.html" class="listMenuChild--title">Publikationen </a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="listMenuChild">
                        <a href="tools.html" class="listMenuChild--title">Hilfsmittel </a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="listMenuChild">
                        <a href="contact.html" class="listMenuChild--title">Kontakt / Lageplan </a></li>

</ul>
```

And here the CSS.

```
.listMenuChild {
    list-style-image: url("../img/bg_li.png");
    margin-top: 5%;
}

.listMenuChild:active {
    list-style-image: url("../img/bg_li_h.png");
}

.listMenuChild:hover {
    list-style-image: url("../img/bg_li_h.png");
}
```

Is it because :active and :hover don't work together?

Any help much appreciated

Comment: You don't need the `:active` state as long as `:hover` has the same design. As long as the item is active it is also hovered because the active state is only as long as you click on the item.

Comment: @oliver it might be because you have `:active` before `:hover` see my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:active` means "While being clicked on or otherwise activated" (e.g. a focusable element would also be activated while you press the Enter key when it has a focus). Note **while**, not *after*.

It doesn't seem to have any effect for you because you never activated it without also hovering it (and your hover rule comes after the active rule).

It sounds like when you say "When the list item is active" you mean "When the link inside the list item has an href attribute that resolves to the URL of the current page". That isn't something you can express with CSS.

Use server side code to add a class to the list item based on the page you are loading and target that class with CSS.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an `:active` class on a non-focussable item like `<li>`, it works only during `mousedown`. If you need to make it work without `:hover`, make it focussable using `tabindex`.

```
<li class="listMenuChild" tabindex="0">
```

The above code is only for it to stay. i.e., Currently the browser applies `:active` for only `mousedown` event. So that occurs only when you are having both `:hover:active` pseudo class:

```css
.listMenuChild:hover:active {backgkround: #999;}
```

Comment: Ok, thank you! Do you know why this question has downvotes? Is it a bad question?

Comment: @olivier Not sure, but you could have searched. Coz this could be a duplicate. Does this work for you?

Comment: There is no limitation of using `:active` on a `li` element. You can use it on every element.

Comment: "You cannot have an :active class on a non-focussable item" — Yes you can.

Comment: @Quentin Corrected, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using pages for each item you could create another class, add it to the list item for each page where that list item is to be highlighted for that page:

```
    .listMenuChild {
    list-style-image: url("../img/bg_li.png");
    margin-top: 5%;
}


.listMenuChildActive {
    list-style-image: url("../img/bg_li_h.png");
}

.listMenuChild:hover {
    list-style-image: url("../img/bg_li_h.png");
}
```

HTML example:

```
<ul class="listMenuItem--s">
                    <li class="listMenuChildActive">
                        <a href="#" class="listMenuChild--title active">Dienstleistungen</a>
                        <ul class="sub-nav">
                            <li><a href="service/treuhandf.html" class="listMenuChild--subtitle">Treuhand &amp; Finanzen </a></li>
                            <li><a href="service/wirtschaft.html" class="listMenuChild--subtitle">Wirtschaftsprüfung</a></li>
                            <li><a href="service/unternehmen.html" class="listMenuChild--subtitle">Unternehmensberatung / Nachfolge</a></li>
                            <li><a href="service/pension.html" class="listMenuChild--subtitle">Pensionierungs-, Vorsorge- und Steuerplanung</a></li>
                            <li><a href="service/informatik.html" class="listMenuChild--subtitle">Informatik</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="listMenuChild">
                        <a href="about.html" class="listMenuChild--title">Über uns</a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="listMenuChild">
                        <a href="publications.html" class="listMenuChild--title">Publikationen </a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="listMenuChild">
                        <a href="tools.html" class="listMenuChild--title">Hilfsmittel </a>

                    </li>
                    <li class="listMenuChild">
                        <a href="contact.html" class="listMenuChild--title">Kontakt / Lageplan </a></li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try swapping these two lines:

```
.listMenuChild:hover {
    list-style-image: url("../img/bg_li_h.png");
}

.listMenuChild:active {
    list-style-image: url("../img/bg_li_h.png");
}
```

Remember this mnemonic phrase:

> **L**o**V**e and **H** **A**te

The 4 pseudo-selectors:

```
a:link      // **L**ove
a:visited   // Lo**V**e
a:hover     // **H**ate
a:active    // H**A**te
```

If they are not in that specific order, they probably will not work correctly.

https://css-tricks.com/remember-selectors-with-love-and-hate/